# What is $X/C - C/C$, where $C \subset X$ are modules and $X/C$ is meant as quotient?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

$C/C$ is the same as {0} ? Basically, then I get confused about the difference between $X-C$ and  $X/C - C/C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X/C$ is a [quotient module](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_module). Its elements are equivalence classes $$x + C = \{x + c : c \in C\}$$ of elements $x \in X$.

In particular, $C/C$ consists of only one class: the trivial class $0 + C$. It is thus canonically isomorphic to the trivial module $\{0\}$.

The notation $X - C$ is usually used to represent the set complement of $C$ in $X$, that is, $$X - C = \{x \in X : x \notin C\}.$$

Note that $X - C$ is a subset of $X$ while the elements of $X/C$ are totally different entities. Also, note that $X - C$ is a subset but not a submodule of $X$. [Do you see why?]

Lastly, if you have a submodule $M$ of $X$ containing $C$, it makes sense to form the quotient $M/C$, which naturally sits inside $X/C$. Therefore, we have a well-defined set complement $X/C - M/C$. As an exercise, can you describe its elements explicitly?

In particular, you can consider the set complement $X/C - C/C$. Again, can you describe its elements explicitly?